# How do I open the inspector group in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using netbeans ide 7.1.1 and all of the groups are open. I cannot find the inspector group. I have the navigator group open, files, palette, program, and, navigator group open. I need the inspector group.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that NetBeans 7.1.1 has renamed the inspector group to Navigator. Previously in order to add a jFilechooser you had to right click the form in inspector and add it from the right click menu. Now in order to get the same result you left click the jForm, then look in the navigator and right click the additional components and add the jFilechooser from there. This is helpful for people following a tutorial that was made using a previous version of NetBeans.

Comment: And the Navigator, in my presumably-default view, is on the toolbar at the left of the screen. It's also on the Window menu.

Answer (score 4):

To go to the inspector window, use Window > Inspector from the NetBeans menu . the window that appears looks like this :

[image]

The image is sourced from [link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/databases_and_java_forms.html) and may not match your project exactly .

Comment: sorry but I dont completely understand. This is what I see. http://postimage.org/image/is8a40ox1/

Comment: Unless they renamed inspector to navigator. I cant find Inspector.

Comment: what is your netbeans version ? If you have 7.1 have a look at http://forums.netbeans.org/topic46624.html

Comment: Thanks. This is unfortunate because now I cannot create a new filechooser window while right clicking the form in navigator.

Comment: Hey Cyprus the answer didnt really help because I am using a different version of netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

Ok,

1. Double Click your Jframe.java (from the Project tree, usually left side)
2. Select the Design tab (looks like a button under your main tab)
3. You should see two tabs on the right, Navigation (previously Inspector) and Properties.

There seems to be a Navigator and a Properties tab in the same panel (both context sensitive), they are difficult to distinguish however since the tab-names start with the name of whatever object is currently selected. (ObjName-Navigator and ObjName-Properties) Since they both represent the same object they cannot be distinguished unless the view/panel is stretched. Also when the Source sub-tab (toggle-button) is selected, there is a different Navigator with different icons and different options for the same objects.

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 and just had the same problem trying to change variable names, following the Oracle's [Converter Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/logic.html). I learned the AWT back in Java 1.3 and am still catching up with all these fancy new tools, I like the features but I do not always appreciate how they have been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way out is to customize the behavior of netbeans in such a way that a keyboard shortcut activates the inspector window.

I also faced similar problem (Netbeans 6.9) and I did this :

Goto **Tools**->**Options**. Select **Keymap** tab. Searched for `inspector window`. Assigned a new shortcut combination (`CTRL+J` in my case).

So in essence, whenever I would want the required window, my shortcut combination would call it up :)

Answer (score 1):

do <kbd>Ctrl+7</kbd> 
or in new netbeans 7.3 goto  Window->Navigating->Navigator

Answer (score 1):

1) window + Reset window

a "other components " windows will be open below Project Window

2) click at [JFrame]

ready! there are the components of the old inspector window :)

greetings. Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

For me it wasn't called Inspector, instead it was called Navigator, in my case it was in Windows > Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in NetBeans IDE 8.1 but it solved by  this menu : Windows>Reset Windows.